# Code completion for remotely editing Scala shell scripts

Tags: scala

On my Windows PC I am editing a scala shell script which lives on some remote Linux server. After saving the file in the editor, it gets automatically transfered to the remote system, where I can run it. That's nice.

Any idea how I could get code completion in this scenario (I mean without having to manually manage a local copy of the file)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Login via SSH and edit the file remotely using Vim.

- Vim code completion for Scala: http://eclim.org/vim/scala/complete.html

Uh, and step 1: learn Vim :/

Comment: Well, as your answer is the only one, I guess you deserve the price ;)

Comment: However I solved my problem very differently: now I'm using IntelliJ IDEA with its Scala plugin and commit/push my changes normally. On the target (Linux) machine, I call another script which does a update/pull on the Scala script first, makes it executable (chmod +x) and then calls it with exec.